# bastante: enough or too much?

Tags: traducción, uso-de-palabras, adjetivos

I have seen *bastante* translated as *enough*, *plenty*, or even *too much*. What range of meanings does *bastante* have? How can you determine whether it means *just enough* or *too much*?

Comment: _Too much_ is better translated as _demasiado_

Comment: *Bastante* comes from the verb *bastar* (to be enough, suffice). Spanish at times tends to be exaggeration-prone: that is why at times *bastante* y *demasiado* are sometimes used interchangeably.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the spectrum is comparable with English:

- insuficiente - not enough / insufficient
- suficiente - enough / sufficient
- bastante - plenty
- demasiado - too much

I usually hear 'bastante' used when implying more than 'enough'; although it's not exactly the same as 'plenty', it's pretty close in a lot of cases:

> Comí suficiente.  "I ate enough" (ie, but no more)
>
> Comí bastante.  "I ate plenty" (ie, as much as I could possibly want)
>
> Comí demasiado.  "I ate too much" (ie, now I feel sick)

Answer (score 3):

1. Enough (or just enough)

   > "Ya he tenido **bastante**!" (I've had enough of this!). Maybe this is the meaning you confuse with "too much".
2. Quite

   > "Mi perro es **bastante** viejo" (My dog is quite old).

Comment: Agreed. I've never seen `bastante` used to mean *too much*.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [RAE](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltConsulta?TIPO_BUS=3&LEMA=bastante), *bastante* means "enough" or "quite a bit", like c4sh says in [their answer](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/971/80). I've never seen it translated as *too* much:

> **bastante.**
>
> 1. adj. Que basta.
> 2. adv. c. Ni mucho ni poco, ni más ni menos de lo regular, ordinario o preciso; sin sobra ni falta.
> 3. adv. c. No poco. *Es bastante rico Bastante bella*

And these are all the meanings listed.